# How to substitute text from files in git history?

Tags: git, substitution, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

I've always used an interface based git client (smartGit) and thus don't have much experience with the git console.

However, I now face the need to substitute a string in all .txt files from history (so, not erasing the whole file but just substituting a string). I found the following command:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git ls-files -z "*.php" |xargs -0 perl -p -i -e "s#(PASSWORD1|PASSWORD2|PASSWORD3)#xXxXxXxXxXx#g"' -- --all
```

I tried this, and unfortunately noticed that while the password did get changed, all binary files got corrupted. Images, etc. would all be corrupted.

Is there a better way to do this that won't corrupt my binary files?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I got mixed up with something. The actual code that caused binary files to get corrupted was:

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter "find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/originalpassword/newpassword/g' {} \;"
```

The code at the top actually *removed* all files with my password strangely enough.

Comment: Doesn't solve your problem, but this is similar to a question I asked a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225454/removing-private-information-from-old-git-commits

Comment: Indeed, there are many answers on how to remove files. I need to substitute a string though.

Comment: @Jimmy Cuadra, please see my edit, I actually used a different script, got mixed up. Maybe it helps you in getting the right command.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can avoid touching undesired files by passing `-name "pattern"` to `find`.

This works for me:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i -e \
    's/originalpassword/newpassword/g' {} \;"
```

Comment: I tried this, but looking at the git history, all the files remain the same... Do I have to 'rebase' or something (I'm so new) and if so how do I do that?

Comment: @Volte Most likely the regular expression you're using is not matching anything. This command will rewrite the repository history (like a rebase), provided that the expression matches something.

Comment: You were right. Turned out I was searching for .php files when I meant to be searching for .h :P That's what I get for blind-copy-paste haha. Cheers.

Comment: Your script doesn't work for me (in Cygwin on Windows). However this works: `git filter-branch --tree-filter "find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/originalpassword/newpassword/g' {} \;"`

Comment: This saved my @$$ ! TY @jweyrich , shor tsweet one liner for the win.

Comment: In my case it was necessary to use the command with `-- --all` at the end as for example all _tags_ on my original branch weren't properly copied to the resulting branch

Comment: how would one place a `\n` in the `newpassword` section?

Comment: This takes forever... :\

Comment: Beware of line returns in Windows. Even if sed does not match the string, it still can change the line returns of output lines. This brings an entire file change without any match.

Comment: `git show $oldcommitid` still works, also after removing `.git/refs/original` and using `git reflog expire` and `git gc` with various options (like from the BFG info page). The contents of the new commit IDs look good (all the way until initial commit) so the replacement worked, but it doesn't get rid of the old data. One's only hope might be that the old commit IDs are not discoverable after recreating the remote system and pushing to there.

Answer (score 123):

I'd recommend using the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a simpler, faster alternative to `git-filter-branch` specifically designed for rewriting files from Git history.

You should carefully follow these steps here: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage - but the core bit is just this: download the [BFG's jar](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#download) (requires Java 7 or above) and run this command (where `my-repo.git` is the folder name of the bare clone of your repo):

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar  --replace-text replacements.txt -fi '*.php'  my-repo.git
```

The `replacements.txt` file should contain all the substitutions you want to do, in a format like this (one entry per line - note the comments shouldn't be included):

```bsh
PASSWORD1 # Replace literal string 'PASSWORD1' with '***REMOVED***' (default)
PASSWORD2==>examplePass         # replace with 'examplePass' instead
PASSWORD3==>                    # replace with the empty string
regex:password=\w+==>password=  # Replace, using a regex
regex:\r(\n)==>$1               # Replace Windows newlines with Unix newlines
```

Your entire repository history will be scanned, and `.php` files (under 1MB in size) will have the substitutions performed: any matching string (that isn't in your *latest* commit) will be replaced.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: unbelieveable! BFG is incredible!

Comment: This just helped me tremendously.  Thank you for such an awesome project. I donated too.  Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks @Bane - really glad it helped, and thanks for supporting the project!

Comment: +1 as I just used BFG for fixing an SQL script that the dev team let get out of control. Though you need to highlight the default of under 1MB on your usage page Roberto, it took a long while of head scratching before it was apparent that that was why my text replace wasn't happening.

Comment: The newlines replacement is a life saver when migrating a mixed Windows/Linux team from Subversion to Git!

Comment: I tried using BFG on my repo, but I get "BFG aborting: No refs to update - no dirty commits found??" I use this:  ---> `java -jar /C/Users/user/bfg-1.12.12.jar --filter-content-including '*.{php,inc,sql,txt,htm,html,js,css,xml}' --replace-text /w/Dev/\!GIT/CVS_ident_replace.txt /w/Dev/\!GIT/repo`

CVS_ident_replace.txt:
`regex:(//\s*\$Id:).*\$==>$1\$               # Replace CVS Ident`

Comment: @RobertoTyley After doing the steps outlined in https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage, how should we update our local history? I did `git pull origin master`. Was this a mistake? Should I have done `git clone`? Because after pushing again I noticed that the replacements made with `bfg` are gone.

Comment: It'd be great if examples like the above were listed on the BFG website! I had to google this SO question again to find them.

Comment: @RobertoTyley Is there any way to do this only for files on certain path of the repo? I have several files with the same extension, but I want to do the cleanup only on the ones under an specific directory.

Comment: Why is this not part of the official BFG docs? I'd send a PR but after a cursory look at the repo it seems there are many open PRs which sought to improve the project's documentation/`README`, which makes me feel there's no point.

Comment: Wow, I should actually have said "Why is this STILL not part of the official BFG docs?"... Just realised I'd already commented in the same vein almost 4 (!) years ago, lol(sob).

Comment: BFG didn't work. IT found the text, but still present on the revisions. Also, tried to DELETE the file, and nothing...

Comment: Just stumbled upon this, great project! Does exactly what I want it to do in the shortest amount of time, thanks mate

Comment: What is the `-fi` option? I couldn't find any [documentation](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) on it.

Comment: `-fi` means `--filter-content-including`, related help request: https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/117

Comment: What is `my-repo.git`? Is it the repo's url that is used in `git clone` command?

Answer (score 22):

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), [**`git filter-branch` (and BFG) is deprecated**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

[**`newren/git-filter-repo`**](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) does **NOT** do what you want.
It has an example that is **ALMOST** what you want in its [example section](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES):

```
cd repo
git filter-repo --path-glob '*.txt' --replace-text expressions.txt
```

with `expressions.txt`:

```
literal:originalpassword==>newpassword
```

However, **WARNING**: As [Hasturkun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20270/hasturkun) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110652/how-to-substitute-text-from-files-in-git-history/58252169?noredirect=1#comment116583364_58252169)

> Using `--path-glob` (or `--path`) causes `git filter-branch` to **only keep files matching those specifications**.
> The functionality to only replace text in specific files is available in bfg-ish as `-fi`, or the [`lint-history` script](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/b1606ba8ac8393d704ba41319c0bba3e334f3341/contrib/filter-repo-demos/lint-history).
> Otherwise, it looks like this is only currently possible with a custom commit callback.
> See [`newren/git-filter-repo` issue 74](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/74)

Which makes senses, considering the `--replace-text` option is itself a [blob callback](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#CALLBACKS).

---

Q1 2024, [`newren/git-filter-repo` issue 74](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/74#issuecomment-1994508381) proposes ([from Daniil](https://github.com/Challanger524)):

> Solution
>
> `git filter-branch --tree-filter "find . -path './src/*' -regextype egrep -regex '.*\.(hpp|cpp)' -exec perl -0777 -pe 's{\n\n\n+}{\n\n}g' -i {} \;" <branch/HEAD/hash..HEAD>`
>
> It was replacing "`>1 blank lines`" with single one

Comment: this wasnt working, so I went through the documentation. You have a small typo. Inside the expressions.txt it should be literal:originalpassword==>newpassword

Comment: @KausUntwale Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly. Don't hesitate to edit it if you see anything else.

Comment: I tried this on a repo, the result was a repo with a single commit, and with only the file mentioned in --path-glob. I expected that the many many commits in my repo was still there and files not matched by the glob was untouched.

Comment: @Otzen It should have worked the way you expected. Not sure what went wrong there.

Comment: Using `--path-glob` (or `--path`) causes `git filter-branch` to only keep files matching those specifications. The functionality to only replace text in specific files is available in `bfg-ish` as `-fi`, or the `lint-history` script. Otherwise, it looks like this is only currently possible with a custom commit callback. See also https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/74

Comment: @Hasturkun Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. And added the link to the `lint-history` script.

Answer (score 6):

I created a file at /usr/local/git/findsed.sh , with the following contents:

```
find . -name 'githubDirToSubmodule.sh' -exec sed -i '' -e 's/What I want to remove//g' {} \;
```

I ran the command:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "sh /usr/local/git/findsed.sh"
```

**Explanation of commands**

When you run git filter-branch, this goes through each revision that you ever committed, one by one. --tree-filter runs the findsed.sh script on each committed revision, saves it, then progresses to the next revision.

The find command finds a specific file or set of files and executes (-exec) the sed editor on that file. sed is a command that takes the regex after s/ and replaces it with the string between / and /g (blank in my example). {} is a reference to the files path that was given by the find command. The file path is fed to sed, so that sed knows what to work on. \; just ends the -exec command.

Seperating the shell script and command out into seperate pieces allows for less complication when it comes to quotes '' or "".

**Peculiarities**

I successfully implemented this on a mac, and apparently sed is a particular (older?) version on macs. This matters, as it sometimes behaves differently. Make sure to do sed -i '' or else it was adding a "-e" to the end of files, thinking that that was what i wanted to name my backup files. -i '' says dont make backup files, just edit the files in place and no backup file needed.

Specifying -name 'filename.sh' helped me avoid another issue that I could not solve. There was another file with .sh and that file ended without a newline character. sed for some reason, would add a newline character to the end, despite the 's/blah/blah/g' not matching anything in that file. So instead of figuring out that issue, I just told the find to ignore all other files.

**Additional commands that work**

Additionally, I found these commands to work in the findsed.sh file (only one command at a time, not multple, so comment # the others out):

```
find . -name '.publishNewZenPackFromGithub.sh.swp' -exec rm -f {} \;
find . -name '*' -exec grep -H PassToRemove {} \;
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

**More info on `git-filter-repo`**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252169/895245 gives the basics, here is some more info.

**Install**

As of git 2.5 at least it is not shipped with mainline git so:https://superuser.com/questions/1563034/how-do-you-install-git-filter-repo/1589985#1589985

```
python3 -m pip install --user git-filter-repo
```

**Usage tips**

Here is the more common approach I tend to use:

```
git filter-repo --replace-text <(echo 'my_password==>xxxxxxxx') HEAD
```

where:

- Bash process substitution allows us to not create a file for simple replaces. If your shell does not support this feature, you just have to write it to a file instead:

  ```
  echo 'my_password==>xxxxxxxx' > tmp
  git filter-repo --replace-text tmp HEAD
  ```
- `HEAD` makes it affect only the current branch

**Modify only a range of commits**

[How to modify only a range of commits with git filter-repo instead of the entire branch history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154624/how-to-modify-only-a-range-of-commits-with-git-filter-repo-instead-of-the-entire)

```
git filter-repo --replace-text <(echo 'my_password==>xxxxxxxx') --refs HEAD~2..HEAD
```

**Replace using the Python API**

For more complex replacements, you can use the Python API, see: [How to use git filter-repo as a library with the Python module interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64160917/how-to-use-git-filter-repo-as-a-library-with-the-python-module-interface/64160918#64160918)

Comment: @VonC I forgot to upvote yours!!! I was meaning to do it!!!

Comment: How to echo more than one replacement expression in your one-line solution?

Comment: @s.k `<(echo 'my_password==>xxxxxxxx'; echo 'my_password2==>xxxxxxxx')` or `<(printf my_password==>xxxxxxxx\nmy_password2==>xxxxxxxx\n)` should both work.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com This does not work in Windows from python under git-msys-bash because python does not understand posix notation generated by `<(...)` operator.

Comment: @Andry added a mention. I don't think process substitution is POSIX btw: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309547/what-is-the-portable-posix-way-to-achieve-process-substitution

Answer (score 2):

Could be a shell expansion issue.  If filter-branch is losing the quotes around `"*.php"` by the time it evaluates the command, it may be expanding to nothing, thus `git ls-files -z` listing all files.

You could check the filter-branch source or trying different quoting tricks, but what I'd do is just make a one-line shell script that does your tree-filter and pass that script instead.

Comment: What would this one liner look like?

Comment: The exact thing you're passing to `--tree-filter '...'` right now.

Comment: Good advice; passing an actual executable script to filter-branch is often much easier than trying to deal with all the quoting.

Comment: I am on windows though, does it support bat scripts?

Comment: please see my edit, I actually used a different script, got mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Since this comes up in Google for `git replace text in history`, and since using non-git tools is sometimes more trouble than it's worth, here's a command that **will replace multi-line text** all the way from `${COMMIT}` onwards to `HEAD`.

**Warning: This is NOT for beginners. It uses `git filter-branch`, so all of its caveats/pitfalls/etc. apply. Make sure you've committed/backed up everything you need to save, so you don't lose data.**

With that said, create the alias in Bash as follows:

```
git config --global alias.filter-branch-replace-text '!main() { set -eu && if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION+x}" ]; then set -o pipefail; fi && local pattern patternq replacement replacementq commit && pattern="$1" && shift && replacement="$1" && shift && commit="$1" && shift && local sed_binary_flags="" && if [ msys = "${OSTYPE-}" ]; then sed_binary_flags="-b"; fi && patternq="$(printf "%s" "${pattern}" | sed ${sed_binary_flags} "s/'\''/'\''\\\\'\'''\''/g")." && patternq="'\''${patternq%.}'\''" && replacementq="$(printf "%s" "${replacement}" | sed ${sed_binary_flags} "s/'\''/'\''\\\\'\'''\''/g")." && replacementq="'\''${replacementq%.}'\''" && git filter-branch --tree-filter "for path in $(printf "%s\n" "$@" | sed ${sed_binary_flags} -e "s/'\''/'\''\\\\'\'''\''/g" -e "s/\(.*\)/'\''\1'\''/" | tr "\n" " ")"'\''; do if [ -f "${path}" ]; then perl -0777 -i -s -p -e "s/\\Q\$q\\E/\$s/sgm" -- -q='\''"${patternq}"'\'' -s='\''"${replacementq}"'\'' -- "${path}"; fi || break; done'\'' "${commit}~1..HEAD" --; } && main'
```

and you can then invoke it from Bash as follows:

```
git filter-branch-replace-text \
    $')\r\n{' \
    $') /* EOL */\r\n{' \
    "${COMMIT}" \
    src/*.txt
```

Note that **this performs literal text replacement, not regular expression replacement**.

If you need regexes, you'll need to remove the `\Q` and `\E` in the Perl command (which perform escaping) and properly escape the strings as needed for the `s/$q/$s/sgm` command yourself.

And if you want to pretty-print the script, you can format it like this:

```
(f="$(git --no-pager config --get alias.filter-branch-replace-text)" && eval "${f%&&*}" && declare -f "${f%%()*}")
```