# Why repository size doubles when i copy notes?

Tags: git, subgit, bfg-repo-cleaner, git-notes

I import SVN repository using Subgit, which is an excellent tool doing it fast and supporting custom svn layout. Subgit saves git commit -> svn revision reference in `git notes`. Every commit has revision number in notes, you can see it with `git log`.

After SVN->git import I use BFG repo cleaner to clean old project repository from binaries like jars, dlls etc.
BFG does not rewrite links between git notes and changed commits but fortunately it leaves `object-id-map.old-new.txt` file.

I use this file to copy notes from old commits to new ones:

`cat object-id-map.old-new.txt | git notes copy --stdin`

After copying notes i remove them from old objects:

`cat object-id-map.old-new.txt | cut -d' ' -f 1 | git notes remove --stdin --ignore-missing`

The problem is that after fixing git notes repository size becomes 2 times bigger (even if i clone without `--bare`). Why?

Example: I have imported repo from svn with Subgit and have 400Mb `.git`. Then i apply BFG and get 40 Mb bare repository. I want to restore git notes by moving (copying and removing) them with 2 commands above, but unfortunately repo's size grows from 40 Mb to 80 Mb.
I try to execute `git notes prune` and `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive` which is recommended by BFG, but still have 80 Mb.

UPD: can't reproduce 40 Mb repo now:/ It is 80 after BFG cleanup and 86 after copying notes

Comment: Probably it is notes history: `git log refs/notes/commits`.

Comment: Could you try these 2 commands one after another? `git -c gc.autoDetach=0 -c gc.reflogExpire=0 -c gc.reflogExpireUnreachable=0 -c gc.rerereresolved=0 -c gc.rerereunresolved=0 -c gc.pruneExpire=now gc --prune --aggressive` and `git -c gc.autoDetach=0 -c gc.reflogExpire=0 -c gc.reflogExpireUnreachable=0 -c gc.rerereresolved=0 -c gc.rerereunresolved=0 -c gc.pruneExpire=now prune`

Answer (score 1):

Three evolution in Git (since 2017) and tools around Git should help with this issue:

- One: a tool like [**github/git-sizer**](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) will give you an idea of what is taking so much space.
- Two: [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (that I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252169/6309)) now replaces BFG or gilter-branch.  [Install it first](https://superuser.com/a/1589985/141). (`python3 -m pip install --user git-filter-repo`).
  It will leaves less data after cleaning jars/binaries you do not want.

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
```

- Three: objects that lost references can be pruned away, even when they have notes attached to it (and these notes will become dangling, which in turn can be pruned with "[`git notes prune`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d590ae5560619108c437a76f3ebd5b0fd9ed8fcf/Documentation/git-notes.txt#L118)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes#Documentation/git-notes.txt-prune))</sup>).
  This has been clarified in the documentation with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), .

See [commit fa9ab02](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa9ab027bac58e4133b6fcea82c459934edb03b1) (10 Feb 2021) by [Martin von Zweigbergk (`martinvonz`)](https://github.com/martinvonz).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d590ae5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d590ae5560619108c437a76f3ebd5b0fd9ed8fcf), 25 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa9ab027bac58e4133b6fcea82c459934edb03b1): clarify that refs/notes/ do not keep the attached objects alive
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Martin von Zweigbergk</sup>

> [`git help`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fa9ab027bac58e4133b6fcea82c459934edb03b1/Documentation/git-help.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help))</sup> gc contains this snippet:
>
> ```
> "[...] it will keep [..] objects referenced by the index,
> remote-tracking branches, notes saved by git notes under refs/notes/"
> ```
>
> I had interpreted that as saying that the objects that notes were attached to are kept, but that is not the case.
> Let's clarify the documentation by moving out the part about [`git notes`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fa9ab027bac58e4133b6fcea82c459934edb03b1/Documentation/git-notes.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes))</sup> to a separate sentence.

`git gc` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fa9ab027bac58e4133b6fcea82c459934edb03b1/Documentation/git-gc.txt#L120-L127):

> objects referenced by the index, remote-tracking branches, reflogs
> (which may reference commits in branches that were later amended or
> rewound), and anything else in the `refs/*` namespace.
>
> Note that a note
> (of the kind created by '`git notes`') attached to an object does not
> contribute in keeping the object alive.
> If you are expecting some
> objects to be deleted and they aren't, check all of those locations
> and decide whether it makes sense in your case to remove those
> references.