# How to modify only a range of commits with git filter-repo instead of the entire branch history?

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I want to use `git filter-repo` to automatically apply some scripted style-guide refactoring for my multi-commit pull requests.

Therefore I want to apply the operations only to the few latest new commits I'm pushing, but not touch anything else in older history.

Is there a way?

For the sake of concreteness, here's a test repo : https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-filter-repository and a sample blob operation:

```
# Install git filter-repo.
# https://superuser.com/questions/1563034/how-do-you-install-git-filter-repo/1589985#1589985
python3 -m pip install --user git-filter-repo

# Usage.
git clone https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-filter-repository
cd test-git-filter-repository
printf 'd1==>asdf
d2==>qwer
' > replace.txt
git filter-repo --replace-text replace.txt --refs HEAD
```

based on: [How to replace a string in a whole Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950829/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-whole-git-history/64153992#64153992)

The above would affect all 3 commits of the test repo. Is there a way to affect only the last 2 commits instead for example?

A blob operation should work perfectly for my use case, as I only want to touch blobs that my commits modified.

I couldn't find it easily [in the documentation](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/7b3e714b94a6e5b9f478cb981c7f560ef3f36506/Documentation/git-filter-repo.txt#L155).

I also asked on their issue tracker: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/157

Tested on git-filter-repo ac039ecc095d.

Comment: Use an interactive rebase?

Answer (score 8):

Try specifying a commit range as your `--refs` argument :

```
git filter-repo ... --refs HEAD~2..master
```

In the documentation ([link](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_miscellaneous_options)), I haven't found an explicit statement saying that commit ranges are vaild values for `--refs <refs+>`, but [the code says](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/d79ea709b7a3cbe1540cc95d90f012d337778f83/git-filter-repo#L3615) that it is passed straight to `git fast-export`, so they are in practice.