# git-filter-repo replace text by expression in a single file

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252169/6630397), I've tried to run [git-filter-repo](https://www.mankier.com/1/git-filter-repo) on a git local repo to replace some plain data in a **single** `docker-compose.yml` file using this `expressions.txt` file:

```
literal:DB_NAME=my_secret_database==>DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
literal:DB_PASSWORT=my-secret-password==>DB_PASSWORT=${DB_PASSWORT}
```

and running it as:

```
$ git-filter-repo --path-glob 'docker-compose.yml' --replace-text expressions.txt --force
```

***disclaimer** on the usage of `--force`: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#FRESHCLONE

The resulting message seems fine:

```
Parsed 212 commits
New history written in 0.39 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
HEAD is now at f7544c8 Refactor docker-compose file # <-- this was definitely NOT my HEAD prior to that
Enumerating objects: 33, done.
Counting objects: 100% (33/33), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Writing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
Total 33 (delta 12), reused 33 (delta 12), pack-reused 0
Completely finished after 0.49 seconds.
```

But then, many (many!) files simply disappeared from my repo, such as (non-exhaustive):

> init.sh
> .gitignore
> .dockerignore
> requirements.txt
> Dockerfile
> Dockerfile.dev
> ...

And I only got 11 commits left (/212 initially), strangely only those including modifications on the `docker-compose.yml` file, and I only have two branches left, again, only the ones including the `docker-compose.yml` file, all others are gone. I feel like I'm living in a wrong mirror world...

What did I do wrong/missed?

If that helps:

```
$ git-filter-repo --version
10401e45d5f0

$ git --version
git version 2.30.0
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `--path-glob` (and friends) selects which files to keep in history, so you basically asked it to only keep `docker-compose.yml` and nothing else. I suggest you read the section about Path based filtering in the documentation. Were you trying to limit the text replacement to those files?

Comment: Hmm, as the title of the linked question suggested (I found it on the top google links), yes, I am actually searching for a way to replace some expression by some other in this single file only (avoiding to search in all other files because I know they are healthy). But I naturally want to keep the rest as is. And to keep this file, after the replacement of course.

Comment: I don't think that's an actual option at present, because content filtering is done over blobs, and blobs don't have names (an entry in a tree has a name and points to a blob, but multiple files might share a blob). You might want to request that as a feature (though I don't know how practical it is to implement).

Comment: Actually, it might be possible using `git filter-repo`'s contrib script `bfg-ish`, which duplicates BFG's filtering behavior (`-fi` flag). I haven't actually tried it out myself, though.

Comment: By simply removing the `--path-glob` option with its parameter, it seems to have done the job correctly as I only have the expression in that file, of course.

Comment: related: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/74