# How enable/disable secret scanning in Azure/VSO

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-commit

in VSO, I have tried push the code without taking latest, when did that, my code got pushed locally. After pulling the latest code when i tried to push again to Central repository I am getting the below error.
I had credentials in few files, after removing it also I'm getting the same error.
Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks in Advance...!!!

> If these are valid credentials, even for non-production resources, you must remove them from Git’s branch history by resetting your branch or squashing all commits.
> See https://aka.ms/1escredscan for instructions. Please report any false positives to 1ESSecTools@microsoft.com.

> NOTE: It is not enough to remove the secrets and push another change. You must reset your branch according to the instructions.

> If this is a false positive, you can bypass credential scanning (for this push alone) by running these commands, assuming that you have no staged changes:

```sh
git commit -m "**DISABLE_SECRET_SCANNING**" --allow-empty`
git push
```

> Alternatively, see https://aka.ms/1escredscan for instructions on how to use the hash values emitted above in a suppressions file to suppress false positives.)
> failed to push some refs to 'https://DevRepository'

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: rejected Dev -> Dev (VS403654: **The push was rejected because it might contain credentials or other secrets.**

Comment: Your question (and the error message) literally has the answer: "you must remove them from Git’s branch history by resetting your branch or squashing all commits" and "You must reset your branch according to the instructions."

Comment: 1escredscan?  1essectools?  Maybe you meant to post this question on an a different site?

Comment: @rickvdbosch I wanna know how to do it, 
As per the suggestion, it says run this command to disable "git commit -m "**DISABLE_SECRET_SCANNING" --allow-empty git push**"
but how do I enable back?
This can be done only through command or we have any UI for it?

Comment: @EdwardThomson If so, could you please share the appropriate forum where I can post this question. :)

Comment: @HabeebShaheryaar It looks like you're internal to Microsoft?  If so, the internal Microsoft stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

> I had credentials in few files, after removing it also I'm getting the same error

That would create a new commit where those credentials are gone.
But said credentials would *still* be there in past commits.

You would need to [remove that sensitive data](https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository), possible with a [`git filter-branch --tree-filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114121/6309) or the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

Then force push.

> As per the suggestion, it says run this command to disable "`git commit -m "DISABLE_SECRET_SCANNING" --allow-empty git push`" but how do I enable back?

I presume the commit with a message "`DISABLE_SECRET_SCANNING`" means don't scan for sensitive data *past* that commit (ie, in older commit).
But I would assume the scan is *still* done for newer commits, so you don't have to worry about "enabling it back".