# Git reset -- hard was not working when I tried to delete my history

Tags: git, github

**I'm facing a problem on a git ..**

I did accidentally commit a piece of API information to the git remote repository:
I want to remove API information but keep "`SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`" in the file.

**I did**

I tried to delete the previous commit by using a

```
git reset --hard <id>
```

but that's not working ..

My default branch is `develop`.
But now I'm working on `feature` branch.

I'm not yet merging the feature to the `dev` branch.

In this situation, what's the best option for me?
This is a personal project.

**I Want**

What I want to the thing is to remove only API information and keep `.env`. file in the feature branch (delete the history)

Comment: Note to moderator; this is on topic.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (that I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252169/6309)).

[Install it first](https://superuser.com/a/1589985/141). (`python3 -m pip install --user git-filter-repo`)

Then:

```
git filter-repo --replace-text <(echo 'my_api-information==>xxxxxxxx') HEAD

# Or, for only the last 2 commits:
git filter-repo --refs HEAD~2..HEAD --replace-text <(echo 'my_api-information==>xxxxxxxx')
```

HEAD means it will change only your current branch commits.