# Git push RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: git, https, gitlab, repository

I have a project that contains some `large folders` that I ignore through `.gitignore`, but when I `git add and commit` I find that the ratio is smaller but not as expected, the following **error** occurs in the final stage of `git push`

```
Total 8494 (delta 285), reused 8494 (delta 285)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502 Bad Gateway
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

The project size is as follows

```
# du -h --max-depth=1 .
...
...
4.2G    ./.git
...
...
16G     ./project
20G     .
```

> My project uses ***Gitllab*** for repository.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

Comment: I can't say for sure whether this is due to the large project size or a separate network issue. If it is the size however, you should consider using Git Large File Storage: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/

Answer (score 1):

First, use [**github/git-sizer**](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) to get an idea of what is taking so much space.

Then try and delete any large file (that you now `.gitignore`, but which is still part of your past commit history)

For that, use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (that I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252169/6309)).

[Install it first](https://superuser.com/a/1589985/141). (`python3 -m pip install --user git-filter-repo`)

Then, for example:

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
```