# GitHub push fails with RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32

Tags: git, github

I have committed my work and I want to push it on my repo on the github

but the push fails and this error is displayed:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Total 10 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Done
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check first if your work you just committed made your repository too big to be pushed to GitHub.

You can use a tool like [**github/git-sizer**](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) to get an idea of what is taking so much space.

If you see an element too large which should not be there, try and delete it (after you now `.gitignore` it, but it would still be part of your past commit history)

For that, use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (that I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252169/6309)).

[Install it first](https://superuser.com/a/1589985/141). (`python3 -m pip install --user git-filter-repo`)

Then, for example:

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
```

Answer (score 6):

Try increasing your push limit.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 15728640
```

Hope it helps! :)