# Is there a simple way to push commits from R

Tags: git, github, rstudio

I created a repository on Github to show my work in R but every time I try to push to my remote repository I get this message

```
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I found this answer
[GitHub push fails with RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65420397/github-push-fails-with-rpc-failed-curl-55-ssl-write-returned-syscall-errno)
but I don't understand where should I try to apply the suggested solution. I think my problem is very simple and the answer I found is too complex for it.

I tried doing a smaller commit (just adding a line to the text in README.md ) and push it
and I get the same error, that makes me think there is no issue with the size of my commit. I think the problem is somewhere else but I don't know where should I search for an answer.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Be aware that pushing one commit also pushes all *previous* commits up to and including that one commit, unless the receiving Git already has those commits.

Comment: Ok so where can check all the commits and start over again, because once I selected one particular commit and tried to push it it disapears from my commit list

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "disappears from my commit list". Perhaps this is an Rstudio thing, that it has a list of commits somewhere? I can only address things from the Git side: `git branch`, `git log`, and the like.

Comment: I found out that the problem arises with large files so I started again to create my repository and upload file by file. My repository size is close to 1 GB and Github won't allow me to commit large files (even 46 mb) but apparently I found a way to do it through Git LSF and I'm trying this now (https://git-lfs.github.com/).

Comment: Ah: be aware that Git-LFS (LFS, not LSF) is a set of wrappers that trick Git a bit. You tell the wrappers which files *not* to put in Git, and the wrappers arrange for those files to be stored on the LFS server instead. They trick Git into storing, in Git, a file that says "get this file from the LFS server". The file appears in your working tree (because that's *not* managed by Git itself: the wrappers are doing that now) but *never goes into Git at all*.

Comment: This is a fine way to sidestep the size limits, but be aware that GitHub will only store a limited amount of large-files in their LFS servers before they start charging money. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and you are right I had a typo I meant LFS.