# Index size exceeded 5GB

Tags: git, bitbucket

One of my team member had committed 2.3 GB files in the git repo hosted on bitbucket. we weren't able to push new commit to remote, so I asked him to delete the file and now index size is exceeded over 5GB.

This because git is tracking the deletion of that binary files also

I managed to clear 400MB using [bfg](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

I want git to completely forget about those files located in `app/TFDeeper` folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried the commands, now index size is 6.4GB -,-

Answer (score -1):

> I tried the commands, now index size is 6.4GB

Not with the recommended [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (that I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252169/6309)).

[Install it first](https://superuser.com/a/1589985/141) (`python3 -m pip install --user git-filter-repo`)

Then, for example:

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
```

Then use a tool like [**github/git-sizer**](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) to check if there is anything else still taking too much space.

Comment: After running this command, It actually deleted all files  and index size is reduced to 2GB :3

Comment: @tbhaxor Yes, it is the right tool for the job. What does git-sizer return? Any large file left?

Comment: Now i can't eent cd into that directory. -,-. So let's wait for some more answers

Comment: @tbhaxor Is it possible to check `git-sizer` in a new local clone of that same repository?