# laravel project size got extra large after downloaded from git hub

Tags: laravel, git

We were working on a Laravel project using git hub pull push method.

Recently we downloaded our project (our work is not done yet, only 40% done so far ) .

Now we found the project size 480+ mb . What we do ?

Comment: Did you add vendor directory to .gitignore?

Comment: Run a usage analysis tool to see what takes the space. We can't just speculate what could have happened.

Comment: @Beller No I did not, in fact this my first work in git - that's why I missed a lot of procedure I guess

Comment: @apokryfos I actually downloaded the zip file from git and deployed it on server running catche/route clear command in cmd (hope this info will help you to get my issue )

Comment: no actually that raises more questions than it answers. Is the zip file what's 480mb? And also which folder takes most space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

- clone the repository
- run the tool [**github/git-sizer**](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) to see exactly what is taking so much space.

That is:

```
cd /path/to/local/cloned/repository
git-sizer --verbose
```

Then you can apply the tool [`newren/git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) ([mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252169/6309), do [install it first](https://superuser.com/a/1589985/141)) to remove any large element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped