# GitHub - Large Files Detected - Can't Push

Tags: angular, github

I am completely unable to push to my GitHub `master` branch.  It is complaining about a 100+ MB file that isn't even part of the front-end, this file is part of a .Net backend.  The front-end is Angular 13.  These are separate projects.

What can I do here?  I've exhausted all options.

It's complaining about an Angular webpack cache file ("4.pack").  I've added this to `.gitignore` and have done what I can from the Git side without luck.

```
remote: error: File .angular/cache/angular-webpack/9a0d55421134d22ded528bf53077d11bd7793d98/4.pack is 126.57 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB        
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github#removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history

describes how to handle this issue. You need to remove it from commits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After upgrading from Angular 12 to 13, cache is too large for Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088051/after-upgrading-from-angular-12-to-13-cache-is-too-large-for-github)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition of ignoring `.angular/cache`, you can consider using [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) instead of the [obsolete `git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

That way, you would:

- [install `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) (python-based)
- delete any large file in your history: `git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 2M` for instance. ([content-based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_content_based_filtering))
- ignore `.angular/cache`
- force push (`git push --force`: make sure to notify any collaborator on that repository)

Comment: Appreciate the assist, do I really need to install Python libs to fix this though?  I don't have any issue with that but you'd think I could resolve this without needing to bring in yet another language.

Comment: @Patrick I agree, this is what I don't appreciate with `git filter-repo`. However, that tool is so much versatile, precise and faster than other alternatives it is worth the additional language installation.

Comment: I have 6 pending commits I need to push, is there any way I can determine which one of these is holding what it thinks is a 100+ MB file and get rid of it?  I am not a master of the git command line.

Comment: @Patrick Yes: https://github.com/github/git-sizer